# PHP include('file.txt') in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, text

I am using strings read from a few .txt files throughout my site to populate certain fields using PHP include, and all of them are working perfectly except for one.

I need to replace a certain variable in my javascript code (It has to be javascript, it's replacing a tumblr post tag) with the value from one of these text files. Using `<?php include('file.txt'); ?>` as I did throughout the rest of my code does not work.

The javascript works perfectly if I manually enter the tag instead of trying to read from the file and the text file just contains a one-word string that needs to be read and used as a js variable.

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm still new to all of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a bit more code. Also read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure. PHP only works in a PHP file (if default config). So PHP in JS will just result in the litteral string, not the content of the file.

If you really want to do this, make a PHP file pretending to be a JS file:

```
// javascript.php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
include("file.txt");
?>
alert(1); // something from the file.
```

Comment: If I do this, what would be the simplest way to read this into the javascript variable back on my index.php page?

Comment: You dont. PHP gets build on the server, then send to the user. Only then will the JS be excecuted. SO by the time you're at the JS point, PHP is stopped. If you want to give it back to PHP, you're gonna have to AJAX or submit a form (the latter being easier to undesrstand flow-wise)

Comment: @christoalberts If you have the javascript inside an index.php file then you can just use my proposed solution with file_get_contents and echo it inside the javascript Variable...

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work? My Javascript is in a index.php file, but using php inside of the script tags doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Check out whatever error you console gives. And check out the acutal sourc to see how the actual code is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: Sorry I misinterpreted your question and thought you generate your javascript through PHP. However you might want to consider using a different approach overall instead of `include()` to change variables throughout your application.

---

PHPs `include()` is for including PHP code which is then interpreted by the PHP engine. In case you just want to read content from a text file consider using something like `<?php echo file_get_contents('file.txt'); ?>` for example.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: The only thing that needs to be done is for a javascript variable to be populated with a short string from a serverside txt file, so any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When using include / require, PHP caches their content between requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$file = include('file.txt'); 
?>
```

throw this variable into the javascript code

and in javascript

`var Text = <?=$file?>`

similarly

`var Text = <? print $file?>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.

I solved it by adding a hidden paragraph to the page, `<p id="hiddentag" hidden="hidden"><?php include('file.txt'); ?></p>`

Then using `var tag = document.getElementById("hiddentag").innerHTML;` which is working perfectly.